# Нужно процедурой perevod(m, k ,s ) из одной системы счисления перевести в другую

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net, системы-счисления

> **Само задание** Заданное целое неотрицательное число s в m-летней системе счисления. Как будет выглядеть это число в k-летней системе? Напишите процедуру perevod (m, k, s), которая выводит переведено число. Если число начинается с буквы, то перед ней не должно быть нуля. Известно, что выполняется условие: 2 ≤ m, k ≤ 36 Для представления чисел 10 ... 35 использовать прописные латинские буквы A ... Z соответственно. Число разрядов числа для перевода не более 1000.

Я вроде бы все сделал но оно не работает!

```
Var
  m, k: integer;
  s: string;
procedure perevod(m, k: integer; s: string);
var
  z,i:longint;
  str:String;
const
  digit:string[16]='0123456789ABCDEF';
begin
if (m<=2) and (m>=36) then
  writeln('Введите число в соответствии с CC:');
if (k<=2) and (k>=36) then
 writeln('Введите число в соответствии с CC:');
 //числа в любую сс
z:=0;
  while s[1]='0' do
    delete(s,1,1);
  for i:=1 to length(s) do
    z:=z*m+pos(s[i],digit)-1;
//перевод любой сс в
str:='';
repeat
    str:=digit[(z mod k)+1]+str;
    z:=z div k;
  until z=0;
end;

begin
  writeln('из какой сс');
  readln(m);
  writeln('число');
  readln(k);
  writeln('в какую сс');
  readln(s);
  perevod(m, k ,s );
end.
```

Comment: почему `m` - целое, а `s` - строка?

Comment: m -- по условию задания система счисления в которой находится число, k - сс в которую нужно перевести,  а s - число которое нам нужно перевести, строка из-за того что может быть число в любой системе(могут появится A B C и т.д.).

Comment: у Вас перепутаны `s` и `k` в `ReadLn` - это первая ошибка. Две рекомендации: научитесь пользоваться отладчиком, уберите `WriteLn` из `perevod` - диалог с пользователем должен происходить до вызова `perevod`.

Comment: А как вы собираетесь получить/увидеть результат?

Comment: Спасибо комментарий @Igor помог, я действительно перепутал     s и     k!

Comment: @Arbron Не за что. Успехов в программировании!